# Slow FileResult in docker container

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, docker, asp.net-core

I have a website which returns a file via a FileResult (I've also tried just a direct link from the View to the .exe).

Outside of a docker container (which is running via Kubernetes on 2 pods, with a Persitent volume Claim to hold a wwwroot/media folder with the .exe in) the download speeds are fast. <1s to download 200mb.

However, when running on the container the download is very slow. ~30minutes. Anyone have any ideas?

The website is a .NET CORE 2 MVC site, running in a Linux Docker container.

Comment: It may be related with NIC configuration of Docker,  did you try to copy this file from docker container to your pc manually?

Comment: @Simonare We've tried copying from the Kuberetes pod to a file and it's pretty quick.

Comment: @Simonare folder*

Comment: kubernetes is totally different platform. I suggest you to copy your file/folder from your docker container to your test platform to see whether the problem is because of the DOCKER itself or .net core related